# Freemarker HashMap loop having pojos

Tags: java, freemarker

i am having HashMap cars, and pojo Car contains attribute 'engines' which is again HashMap.

```
public class Car implements Serializable{
       private Long id;
       private String name;
       private Map<Long,Engine> engines = new HashMap<>();
       ..
       ..
}
public class Engine implements Serializable{
       private Long id;
       private String name;
}
```

Freemarker model

```
final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Map model = new HashMap();
model.put("cars",theCarsMap);
Template tmpl = t.cfg.getTemplate("text.ftl");
tmpl.process(model, sw);
```

Freemarker configuration

```
        cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setCacheStorage(new freemarker.cache.MruCacheStorage(20, 250));
    cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(getClass(), ".");
    cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
```

Template Code:

```
 <#assign rKeys = cars?keys>
 <#list rKeys as rKey>
 Car Details:${cars[rKey].getName()}\n
  --------------------------------------------------\n
 <#assign engines = cars[rKey].getEngines()>
 <#assign tKeys = engines?keys>
 <#list tKeys as tKey>
 ------------------Engine Details-----------------\n
 Name: ${engines[tKey].getName()}\n
 </#list>
 </#list>
```

I am getting following error:

The problematic instruction:

```
${cars[rKey].getName()} [on line 3, column 18 in text.ftl]
```

Is there any thing special handling related to HashMap containing pojos and another Map?

Comment: Paste the *complete* error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does no work with Map with POJOs as values, I have to change to List.... and Also java objects wrappers for primitive types does not work either, change to primitive definition. i.e. Long ---> long

```
<#list cars as c>
 ${c.id!'Unknown'} - ${c.name!'Unknown'}

 <#list c.engineList as t>
    ${t.id!'Unknown'} - ${t.name!'Unknown'}
 </#list>
 </#list>
```

Comment: @agp - I do both of these things (POJOs in maps, object wrappers) regularly. But given that you can't be bothered to give people here enough information to actually help you, I can't be bothered to respond.